# GoogleTV V3 QSB suggestion, change image aspect ratio

Tags: google-tv, android-qsb

I am running into an interesting issue; I have my app providing search suggestions to the QSB along with a movie poster via SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1.
On versions of GTV prior to v3 I would get the poster displayed properly. 
On v3, the suggestion is shown (under other) with only a portion of the poster shown in a square.
TV an movies suggestions, from primetime show appropriately sized suggestion posters in the qsb, is there a way to change the aspect of the suggestion icon displayed or maybe a different field that could be used for the suggestion ?

EDIT : code

I use a basic content provider to read the suggestions from sqlite; I use the following projections; i do not do anything beyond that.

```
    projection = new String[] { Tables.MEDIA_SEARCH + ".rowid AS " + BaseColumns._ID,
                            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
                            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2,
                            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA,
                            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID,
                            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_EXTRA_DATA, 
                            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke with the eng team and design team about this. On V3 the decision was made to constrain the 3rd party provided images to QSB into the square format you are encountering. The suggested method for serving images to qsb and maintain aspect ratio is to provide a square image where you manage the contents of it (1:1 ratio). Unfortunately there is not a way to force the aspect correction in the latest version for your case.

Comment: I edited the post with the projections used with the search suggestions content provider, I posted on G+ the screenshots of QSB suggestions for V2 and V3